# Internet explorer window.resize fails after using document.write

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom

This may be a bug in internet explorer (IE9), wondering if it is known or there is a workaround.

It can be reproduced by opening up the dev console, and executing each of these commands,

```
window.onresize = function() { alert("onresize"); }
```

At this point, when you resize the window, the event fires as expected. Now execute,

```
document.write("test");
```

After this point `window.resize` will be null.

That's probably expected since `document.write` calls `document.open` which clears everything.

However, even if you add back an event handler, it will never fire,

```
window.onresize = function() { alert("onresize"); }
```

Comment: did you try allowing blocked contents (js is blocked sometimes) ?

Comment: [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/382982)

Comment: Just a little question: How you add `window.onresize` back to an *empty* document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the whole script block into the new document. For example:

```
document.write("<div>some html</div><script>window.onsize=function() { alert('onresize'); } </script>
```

This is because when you call document.write it creates a new document with an "empty" url. Where as your original document comes from a different Url (for example, "http://www.yoursite.com/Page1.aspx". The site for the empty Url is not the same as the site of the original Url. And a browser does not allow script in pages from one site calls script in pages from another site (to avoid cross site script attack). Thus it is not possible for you to call a function defined in "http://www.yoursite.com/Page1.aspx" from a page with null Url. As such you have to write the script code itself into the new document.